# ORACLE: SELECT VALUE IF

Tags: sql, oracle, case-when

I am trying to select different values that depend on different conditions, but I don't exactly know, how one can achieve this in SQL/Oracle..

Here is an example:

```
SELECT VALUE (I dont exactly know what to write here)
FROM
  (SELECT 
  (CASE
     WHEN (Select 1 from DUAL) = 1 THEN 'TEST'
     WHEN (Select 1 from DUAL) = 0 THEN 'TEST1'
     WHEN (Select 1 from DUAL) = 0 THEN 'TEST2'
     ELSE 'N/A'
  END) 
FROM DUAL);
```

I want to print different results according to the conditions...For instance, in the example above it should print "TEST"

Comment: Can you be more specific? Provide sample data, expected output and explanation for it.

Comment: Can you show us the actual query?  Your `CASE` syntax looks right.

Comment: You seem to understand that `CASE` is used for this purpose.  What don't you understand?

Comment: Thx for the answers, sry I know my question was not very precise, but MT0 just provided the answer, what I was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide an alias to the `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT alias_for_your_case_value
FROM   (
  SELECT CASE (Select 1 from DUAL)
           WHEN 1 THEN 'TEST'
           WHEN 0 THEN 'TEST1'
           WHEN 0 THEN 'TEST2'
           ELSE 'N/A'
         END AS alias_for_your_case_value
  FROM   DUAL
);
```